# How does Ishto KiGufo work?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, lomdus

How does Ishto KiGufo (ones wife is considered like his own body) work? Meaning, how come in some cases where you can't use a shliach, your spouse may do it for you (see Tur YD 234:1), and yet sometimes we say even though ishto kigufo it's still better to do it yourself (see Bach OC 677:3:1). And why do we apply it in halacha in some places and not others?

A few places I've found are Brachot 24a, Bechorot 35b, Tur YD 234:1, 252:1, Shulchan Aruch YD 314:4, Bach OC 219:3:1, CM 247:1:1, Mishna Brura 367:1, 671:9, Aruch Hashulchan OC 250:3, CM 152:5, 291:53, 339:9, 346:16.

Comment: https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%95_%D7%9B%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%95

Comment: What do you mean by "how does it work"?

Answer (score 4):

To the second question the [Birkat Asher on Devarim 12:12](https://www.sefaria.org/Birkat_Asher_on_Torah%2C_Deuteronomy.12.12.2?lang=bi) asks your question:

.אתם ובניכם ובנֹתיכם ועבדיכם" וגו'. ומעין זה בפסוק יח "אתה ובנך ובתך ועבדך" וגו'. ואילו האשה אינה מוזכרת כלל, וכמו בעשרת הדברות בשבת. כלום זה עניין "אשתו כגופו"? (פ' ראה תש"ן)
בדקתי במקומות שכלל זה מוזכר, בווריאציות שונות, ולא מצאתי לא מקור ולא כלל ברור - מתי אומרים "אשתו כגופו" ומתי לא. מסתבר שעצם אי־איזכור האשה בכל הפסוקים מעין הנ"ל הוא הוא המקור. והרי רשימת המקורות שמצאתי:
(א) בעדות - אדם הפסול להעיד על הבעל משום קורבה, הריהו פסול להעיד גם על אשתו (סנהדרין כח ע"ב).
(ב) המבייש את האשה, חייב לשלם חלק מתשלומי הבושת לבעלה. מכיון שאשתו כגופו, רואים את הבעל כמי שנתבייש, כשביישו את אשתו (כתובות סו ע"א).
(ג) כלל הוא, ש"אין פודין את השבויין יתר על כדי דמיהן". למרות זאת, אדם שאשתו נשבתה, צריך הוא לפדותה אפילו ביותר מכדי דמיה, לפי שאשתו כגופו, וכל אשר לו יתן בעד נפשו (גיטין מה ע"א תוספות ד"ה דלא ליגרבו).
(ד) אף על פי שלמדנו מפסוק שאין אדם יכול לעשות שליח שיסמוך על קרבנו, מכל מקום הוצרכנו ללימוד מיוחד שאין אשתו סומכת, לפי שהיינו אומרים שלוחו אינו כגופו אבל אשתו כגופו (מנחות צג ע"ב).
(ה) אין הבעל יכול להתיר נדרי אשתו שאינם מדְברים שבינו לבינה או של עינוי נפש, בתורת חכם, לפי שאשתו כגופו (רא"ש נדרים פא ע"ב).
(ו) אף על פי שהמהדרין מדליקים בחנוכה נר לכל אחד ואחד מבני הבית, אשתו אינה מדלקת לחוד, שאשתו כגופו (משנה ברורה סימן תרעא סק"ט). (פ' ראה תש"ס)

Just to summarize what I think he is saying: He says that he has checked all the places (I wouldn't say all because he is missing a few I think) and doesn't know when we apply Ishto Kegufo and when we don't. His answer is that anytime the pesukim don't mention a women (in pesukim that give a list of people like Shabbat, 10 commandments) is the makor for saying ishto kegufo. Then he lists 6 times we apply ishto kegufo (even though there are more out there). I don't know if this is true and haven't checked, but its an interesting idea to check.

Comment: maybe i wasn't so clear, but that case in Yevamot and Sanhedrin is totally not what i was looking for, it just happens to have the same words "ishto kigufo". i added some more references to the question, mayeb that will help. Thanx anyways for trying

Comment: Thanks for making it more clear, I will change my answer based on the edits in the question

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference, this doesn't explain all of the places where we say Ishto kiGufo, but gives a nice insight that can be toyed around with.

Answer (score 3):

The Shulchan Arukh (Orach Chayim 73:2) gives an example of how to apply this rule:

> If one was sleeping with his spouse, he may recite [the Shema] by turning away his face to the other side. And [this is so] even without the separation of a cloth because [one's spouse's body] is considered like one's [own] body.